# Is it necessary to specify VIRTUAL_HOST when using an nginx proxy (with docker containers)?

Tags: docker, nginx

I've been looking at a lot of tutorials on docker containers, microservices and nginx proxy. One thing that really caught my attention is that in the docker-compose.yml file, the service that I'd want to start up has a VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable. That way I can start the container by directly referencing the VIRTUAL_HOST.

But do all the containers need to have VIRTUAL_HOST specified? For example, suppose I have 3 containers: A, B and C. If I want all 3 of these containers to be proxied, then do I have to specify a VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable for all 3 of them in the docker-compose file? Is the VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable a prerequisite for Nginx proxy to work properly with these containers? None of the tutorials I checked answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about the [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) image.

> That way I can start the container by directly referencing the VIRTUAL_HOST.

The container is started as soon as you type `docker-compose up` and it's running all the time. `VIRTUAL_HOST` tells the reverse proxy which host requests should be forwarded to this container.

For example if you have a container with `VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.example.com`, then each request made to the revproxy with `foo.example.com` in the `Host` header will be forwarded to this container and its response will be sent by the proxy to client. But if the `Host` header is `bar.example.com`, the request will not be forwarded to that container. Instead, proxy will forward it to a container with `VIRTUAL_HOST=bar.example.com`. If no such container exists, it will try to use the default host specified with `DEFAULT_HOST` variable on the proxy container (not default container). If default host isn't configured, it will return an error.

Without `VIRTUAL_HOST`, the proxy won't know which `Host` this container corresponds to, so no requests will be forwarded.

Comment: But aren't there any other ways for the proxy to identify which container the request should be forwarded to? Perhaps by using the IP address of the container...or something like that?

Comment: @Vktr I think you're misunderstanding the issue. The purpose of this reverse proxy is to distribute requests across multiple HTTP servers based on request data, specifically the `Host` header user's browser sends (which contains website's URL up to the first slash). It needs to somehow know which `Host` header corresponds to which container. The browser doesn't know that the revproxy is there, it also doesn't know that you're running the server in Docker or what container IPs are. That's what this revproxy is for, it hides complexity of your infrastructure. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I totally forgot that the host header is a part of the http request. But what doesn't make sense is this: In many of the tutorials I checked online, the VIRTUAL_HOST is only specified for one service in the docker-compose file. In all the other services, no VIRTUAL_HOST is specified. Why is that? Here is an example of such a tutorial: [Developing with Docker](http://engineering.ifttt.com/oss/2015/10/06/developing-with-docker/). Check part 4. The VIRTUAL_HOST is only specified for one service, despite the fact that this service has links to the other services. Why is that?

Comment: Other services aren't user-facing and accessible through HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you have three separate services that do different things and want routed independently - give each a unique virtual host. Which will then be subsequently used to make a request to that container  (the one with that virtual host env var will respond)

If you have three instances of the same service - then give the same virtual host env var to each and nginx will round robin the requests